# Is $_var correct in PHP?

Tags: php

What is `$_var` in PHP? Why is it used like this?

```
class User 
{
     private $_name;

     public function __construct() 
     {
          $this->_name = "Joseph Crawford Jr.";
     }

     public function GetName() 
     {
          return $this->_name;
     }
}
```

Comment: http://www.phpdynamic.com/guides/beginners/beginning-php-language-syntax/

Comment: @user - **Please could you mark an answer as correct by 'ticking' it on the left**, if any were useful, else I'll delete - cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Some developers like to prefix variables with underscores to show that they are private or protected class variables.

This isn't anything big, it's just opinion. If you want to stick to some 'standards', check out [PSR](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md).

Comment: Isn't PSR for Autloading? How is that related here?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha No, that's one part of it. There's PSR-0, 1 and 2, that covers naming conventions, brackets, autoloading, you name it!

Comment: Oh, I see. You linked to PSR-0 though :P

Answer (score 0):

It just starts with an underscore to visually distinguish that it's a class field in this case. There is nothing special with such variables.

Comment: More likely, to indicate it's a property with limited visibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's an older-style way of signifying a variable as protected or private in PHP4 when there was no differentiation between public, protected and private like there is in PHP5.